# Branching strategy for developing 2 versions in parallel

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

We have our 1.0 on which work is beeing done on and our version 2.0 with even more check-ins and changes. Is there any way to keep them in sync?

We have all kind of changes:

- 1.0 changes only
- 2.0 changes only
- changes for both

The problem is that the code base for 1.0 and 2.0 will differ more and more over time and merging will become a nightmare as both versions mature.

I think simple release branches are not applicable for us because it feels like a Main/Trunk branch is not existent. We can´t merge different behaviors in one single branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided not to use branching at all.
We use feature toggles instead for the migration time and delete the toggles afterwards.